# display data from an xml file upload from the mobile download folder in ListView

Tags: maui

I made this code to download the data from an Xml file that I must load which is in the phone's download file in a ListView. I have no error but my ListView does not display anything, it is empty, I checked the path for the file is good but the loading of the data in the list does not happen, apparently there is only the library `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials` which helps for that but I do not can't get it or install it. Please give me another solution that avoids using the `Microsoft.Maui.Essentials` library.

```
private void LoadXmlFiles()
{
      try
      {
          var downloadsPath = Path.Combine(FileSystem.AppDataDirectory, "Download");
          var xmlFiles = Directory.GetFiles(downloadsPath, "P-COS_ScannerSettings_PCMBU4PQDL1_V1.xml");
          var xmlFileNames = xmlFiles.Select(f => Path.GetFileName(f));
          MyListView.ItemsSource = xmlFileNames;
      }
      catch (Exception ex)
      {
          Console.WriteLine($"Error: {ex.Message}");
      }
}
```

Comment: If you are trying to read the contents of an xml file this code does not do that.  What exactly do you think Essentials will do to help you?

Comment: First, this is not the mobile download folder, it is random folder named download that sits in the application data folder. (Or, as I suspect, does not even exist there). Second, your code, in the best scenario, will be giving a list of file names. (Right now will not even do that). Third, this Essentials API cannot be avoided, if I am right about your intent. Random access to folders is forbidden on Android, for all but very limited use cases ( anti-vir app, backup app, etc) For IOS it is even worse.